# How can we publish updates to 10 Alexa Skills with one click?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

We have more than 10 skills for dry cleaners around the U.S., and they all receive the same updates, but we have to individually publish them. **How can we set up a system that allows us to submit them ALL for review at the same time?**

From the command line is a plausible option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASK CLI to deploy skill with one command per skill
`ASK deploy`

you can choose to deploy lambda only
`ASK deploy -t lambda`

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html

a better solution is to use a CI/CD pipeline